# How to display my sql output into php?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code but instead of displaying my sql output it displays 0

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(c.enno) AS 'noreg' FROM dtr_empinfo c WHERE c.`stats` = 
'Regular'";
$query1 = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query1->execute();
$results=$query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$empcount=$query1->rowCount();
?>
<?php echo htmlentities($empcount);?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're displaying the rowcount of your query which is 0. So even if you used the correct code for displaying records it still won't work as you have nothing to display.

Comment: Also, if you're just displaying the number of records then don't use `htmlentities`.

Answer (score 0):

You use "$sql**1**" here:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(c.enno) AS 'noreg' FROM dtr_empinfo c WHERE c.`stats` = 
'Regular'";
```

, but you use "$sql" here:

```
$query1 = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
```

So, you're running an empty sql command and, therefore, returning 0 rows.

Also, your echo statement is only returning the row count. See code below for instructions on echoing the actual results.

Full Code I used to Test:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

        // Create PDO
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database_name", 'your_database_username', 'your_database_user_password');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(c.enno) AS 'noreg' FROM dtr_empinfo c WHERE c.`stats` = 'Regular'";
        $query1 = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query1->execute();
        $results=$query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $empcount=$query1->rowCount();



        // You're only requesting the row count with this statement:
        $empcount=$query1->rowCount();
        echo htmlentities($empcount);

        // If you want the actual SQL results, do this:
        echo $results[0]->noreg;

        ?>

        <!-- Or, you can echo it within the html, like this: -->
        <?php echo $results[0]->noreg; ?>
        <!-- No htmlentities needed, since it's just a number -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you're displaying `$empcount=$query1->rowCount();` Do read it about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that the first time. See my revised answer, above (new lines added to bottom of php section).

Comment: im kinda newbie here where can i find the answered mark?

Comment: Since you're only returning a number from your sql query, there's no need for html entities. I added a bit to the code to show how to insert it outside the php. ... There should be a big checkmark under the vote up/down bit near the top, left of my answer.